# Read and write simultaneously from a named pipe in C++

Tags: c++, linux, boost-asio, ipc, named-pipes

I have a process A that is writing continuously to a named pipe. It has opened it in O_NONBLOCK | O_RDWR mode.
Another process B is reading continuously from that pipe. It has opened it in O_NONBLOCK | O_RDONLY mode.

Note that I am using boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor and async_write (process A) and async_read (process B) for all this.

Now my issue is that B is not able to read from the pipe, until A stops writing. I want this to happen simultaneously. B's reading capability should only depend on whether data is present or not. It shouldn't be affected by A's writing.

How can I accomplish this?

I have tried changing the modes I have opened the file descriptors in, but to no avail.
I also tried setting stream_descriptor.non_blocking(true);

**Edit:** I am spawning process B from process A using

```
system(command.c_str());
```

Where command holds the executable path. Also, the process is executed in the background. So I am logging to stdout when:

1. Process A calls async_write (Before);
2. Process A has called async_write (after);
3. Process A async_write completion handler executes (inside it);

Similarly:

1. Process B's, async_read is called (before);
2. Process B's, async_read has been called (after);
3. Process B's async_read completion handler executes (inside it).

The output I observe:  
B async read calling 
B async read called 
A async write calling 
A async write called 
A async write completed 
A async write calling 
A async write called 
A async write completed 
. 
. 
. 
<once all of A's writing is done> 
B async read completed 
B async read calling 
B async read called 
. 
. 
.

**Edit:** Thanks for letting me know about system command, but as I mentioned earlier, I am launching the command in backgroud. So what is happening is:

```
command = "./executable &";
```

The '&' symbol is causing system command to return immediately.

Comment: Can you provide a little bit of information on how, exactly, you've determined that "B is not able to read from the pipe, until A stops writing"? What did you to make this conclusion?

Comment: Would an automobile mechanic be able to tell you how to fix your car if you simply said, "My car goes *braaaAAAAP braaaaAAAAPP!* when I try to start it.  How can I fix it?"  No?  Then why would you think someone can fix your code when you don't post it?

Comment: "B is not able to read from the pipe, until A stops writing" How do you know? What exactly you observe? (Observe, not deduce).

Comment: Is there some reason why A is opening its end of the pipe in `O_RDWR` mode instead of `O_WRONLY` mode?  Since B is using `O_RDONLY` mode it seems like A will never receive any data anyway, so using `O_WRONLY` might simplify things for you.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner O_WRONLY won't work in nonblocking mode if there are no readers yet. The usual solution on Linux is to use O_RDWR, but this is not portable to other POSIX OSes.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik
I have added a relevant edit.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Please check out the edit.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I know it may be difficult to figure out the issue without the exact code. But I am trying to explain the observations I made and the issues I faced to see if I am not making a major mistake like "maybe its not possible to accomplish this with named pipes". I will soon post a minimum reproducible example if this doesn't workout. My current code is not easy to separate from the rest.

Comment: What happens if you insert a couple of seconds worth of `sleep` between A's async write calls?

Comment: Reading and writing from something at the same time is not possible. Either the reading or the writing will happen first even if you have multiple threads -one or the other will happen first; the reading or the writing..

Comment: @ztart14578 And I hope you learned now why *describing* code is useless.  Your problem had **nothing** to do with reading or writing to pipes.  It was the **one** line of actual code you posted.

Comment: This was tagged boost, so why not use Boost Process? It has all the goods (and it's based on Asio for async operations) See e.g. this demo https://stackoverflow.com/a/48726975/85371

Comment: This sequence of events is extremely probable if two of your claims are false: (1) the spawned process runs in the background and (2) process B is spawned from process A. If in reality process A is spawned from process B, and the spawned process runs in the foreground as `system` normally does (there is no indication in the text that you do something special to prevent that), then everything falls in place. Otherwise you need to post a [mre], because what you describe is rather improbable.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I'll work on posting a MRE.

Comment: @sehe I was using boost::process::async_pipe initially, but its meant for parent-child communication which is not the case for me. And internally async_pipe is using read and write FDs to a boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor only. So I am trying to use the same thing more suited to my usecase.

Comment: "its meant for parent-child communication" - that's **exactly** what you're doing though. You're right that Boost Process internally uses the same for the pipe. However, what it does **correctly** is to spawn the child process in an asynchronous (nonblocking) way, while still allowing for the FDs to be connected. I'll wait for the MRE

Comment: @sehe, yeah I guess I could have rather used fork(). I was afraid of this earlier because a child process's memory is a copy of parent's memory, but now I realise that exec() could have overcame that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Edit: I am spawning process B from process A using
>
> system(command.c_str());

You might be surprised to learn that `system()` ***waits for the executed command to finish*** before returning, and ***only then*** does this program continue running. This has nothing to do, whatsoever, with named pipes. You observe the same behavior no matter what both processes are doing: process B must finish before process A continues.

That's because, simply, ***that's what `system` does***: it ***stops*** this process, ***executes*** another process, and ***waits*** for that other process to finish. If you go back and look at your textbook's description of `system()` you'll learn that `system()` returns the exit code of the spawned program. Well, to do that, you have to wait until it finishes running, doesn't it?

You can simply replace `system()` with `fork()` and `exec()`.

`system()` is just nothing more than a `fork()`, followed by `exec()`, and a `wait()`. That call to `wait()` is what you got stuck on.

Comment: I think the advice should be "don't ever use `system()`" - it´s a hell to deal with input and output and it's also a security nightmare - you don't know what environment you have to deal with, you don't know what the command enterpreter will be, it's a known entry point for attacks, etc.# - Just don't use `system()`.

Comment: Please check the last edit